# How to handle the paging width

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, scroll-paging

I am using horizontal UICollectionView with paging enabled.What I want is for the page It should move only the half the width of the screen(page),for the remaining pages it will be normal i.e. the size of the screen.How to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

`UICollectionView` inherits from `UIScrollView`, so you can control the scrolling behaviour by overriding the following UIScrollViewDelegate's method like this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat pageWidth = yourCollectionView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((yourCollectionView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    [yourCollectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(page*yourCollectionView.frame.size.width, 1) animated:NO];
}
```

P.S. You need to set `yourCollectionView.delegate = self`

Hope it helps